# A collision for Host ID 'functionsv4placeholdertemplatesi' was detected in the configured storage account

Tags: azure, function, azure-functions, azure-storage-account

We are getting an error message in our function app:

> A collision for Host ID 'functionsv4placeholdertemplatesi' was detected in the configured storage account.

This error seem to be disappearing on random sometimes, and other times it just reappears. We haven't been able to find out the root cause. We can see that the file that is mentioned in single quotes in the error message exists in the connected storage space. Removing it doesn't resolve the problem either as it gets re-created with the same problem.

Deleting every resource connected to the function and the function itself, sometimes solves the problem but the error message reappears again after a couple of weeks, even though the resource is up and running with no apparent problems at first.

This error doesn't seem to be affecting the overall functionality as far as we can se, so the service works as intended.

The solution from Microsoft is to either change the `Function Site Name` to a minimum of `32 characters` or to set a configuration setting for each function name with the setting `AzureFunctionsWebHost__hostid` **(V2+)** or `id` **(V1)**.

We have tried both solution rekommendations but still with no positive results.

Anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you're using the same storage account for the 2 or more Function Apps. Make sure you use separate storage account for separate Function apps. When the same storage account is shared between 2 or more functions they all write to the same storage account blob and leases.

Refer my [**SO answer1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76960287/azure-functions-deployment-slots-best-practice-another-app-likely-has-the-leas/77006205#77006205) and [**SO answer2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77681945/azure-functions-host-was-shutdown-when-an-error-occurs/77689692#) for the same error.

Also, Try creating a separate storage account and mention the File Share location manually with the settings below:-

```
WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE:siliconfuxxxx3
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. interesting, but shouldn't storage accounts be used to be able to consolidate function app root connections? I'm thinking of having multiple Storage accounts just for one function app namespace is a bit too much isn't it? We've never had this problem before in other consolidated architectures we are using. This came up as a problem after we added slot swap functionality for deployment purposes.  Should one have a Storage account for Productions slots and non production slots instead?

Also we would've run out of eligible storage accs / region in our sub pretty fast if this is the case.